# sansmathfonts package warning

Tags: packages, warnings, sansmathfonts

In my environment, I get the following warning:

```
The [I] package option is only compatible with the OT1 and U font encodings. I will ignore the [I] package option..
```

I have no idea what this means or how I can remove it.

The origin of the error is in the package itself:
[image: error and the source of the error]

[image: The place where I include the package]

[image: The same error. Different document]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's the point. I don't have that kind of code. That's why I can't remove it.

Comment: don't show code as an image, add as a code block, preferably as a complete repoducible document that shows the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where do you see it's line 12? I see it's line 47 in the sansmathfonts package. Which I also have a picture from.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added another picture (I know you want it as a code block), but the errors remains the same. It also compiles, but the warning just doesn't go away.

Comment: why are you providing as image? The point of providing an example is to allow people to reproduce the problem and debug it. An image is no help at all. In this case I could guess an example just from the warning text but normally that isn't possible

Comment: I do not get a warning using the default OT1 encoding as in your image (texlive 2022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package warning is badly worded in that it warns `[I]` would not work even if you don't use it. You have not shown any relevant code but presumably you are using a font encoding not in the list it supports. I can demonstrate with Greek `LGR` encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
Package sansmathfonts Warning: The [I] package option is only compatible with t
he OT1 and U font encodings. I will ignore the [I] package option. on input lin
e 47.


Package sansmathfonts Warning: Sans serif text fonts are only provided for OT1,
 T1, and U font encodings. I will not change the sans serif text font. on input
 line 52.
```